# Jquery on delegate specific function to specific handler

Tags: jquery, delegates

OK, so, my code:

HTML :

```
<div id ="close"></div>
<div id="mask">
  <div id="picture">
    <div id="prev"></div>
    <img src="" />
    <div id="next"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Everything what is inside #picture is adding by jquery html(), so I need on() (delegate) to add some function to this elements.

jQuery:

```
$('#close, #mask').on("click", function(){
    closeImg();
});

$('#picture').on("click", '#prevImg', function(){
    prevImg();
});

$('#fixed').on("click", '#nextImg', function(){
    nextImg();
});
```

If I click on #nextImg/#prevImg function closeImg() was called too. And I don't wont it. How to removed handler closeImg() from #nextImg/#prevImg but let call nextImg()/prevImg()? I think, I should to use off(), but I don't uderstand how and I can't find similar example. And my whole effort failed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [`event.stopPropagation()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation) in your `previous` and `next` functions to stop propagating the click event to it's parent.

```
$("#picture").on("click", "#prevImg", function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    prevImg();
});

$("#picture").on("click", "#nextImg", function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    nextImg();
});
```

Comment: Just FYI this doesn't work as the event handlers are delegated. This means the event has already bubbled up the DOM in order for it to be caught. You cannot call `stopPropagation()` here. I made the same mistake :)

Comment: @Phani Kumar M It work, thank you very much. I thought about stopPropagation() , but I used it in the wrong way.

Comment: I thought similar to Rory McCrossan, and to be honest, I'm a little surprise that it work, I need to analize it carefully; but it work :-)

Comment: @Eva Sure... let me know if it doesn't work for me to remove my post.